# Not able to install oracle 19c on windows 10 machine

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle19c

I am trying to install it on windows 10 machine but it's in hang state for long time at first step itself.

Comment: Whcih edition of Oracle? Which edition of Windows? There's so many things it could be. Have you looked in the installation log (default location is`C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\installActions<timestamp>.log.`)

Comment: Have you followed the official Installation Guide for Windows (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/index.html )? Do you meet _all_ of the prereqs, including the _proper edition_ of Windows 10?